# Salesforce Bulk API test in postman

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

How to test salesforce bulk API in postman? Do we really need WSDL to work with bulk api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this but it would require manually writing the soap envelope for each request ([see example](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/)).  However I would suggest using [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html) which lets you import wsdl files and create sample request. All you have to do is provide the inputs, the opensource version is free and would meet your needs.
You dont "need" the wsdl but it makes it easier to determine the call you can make and the parameters you need to pass for the calls, because it describes the webservice that you are trying to use, and because it's a standard many applications support it.

Comment: @jordan thanks for your reply! i tried in Soap UI.but not able to import WSDL in soap project.giving error: Unexpected element: CDATA

Comment: if your wsdl is online send me the link let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WorkBench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) to test salesforce's API otherwise you can use postman to test the REST API of salesforce as described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm)